# Some challenging Series, maximum value and polynomial factor questions

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, contest-math

So I realize that the questions I am gonna ask are going to be a minute's work for some of you but I couldn't do them even after hours of searching for methods or something. They are from a competitive test.

1. If x and y are POSITIVE REAL numbers, such that their sum is 1, find out the maximum value of x<sup>4</sup>y + y<sup>4</sup>x.

Options: A. 1/6    B. 1/8      C. 1/12     D. 1/16

While I know how to do this question via Calculus (Maxima), I can only have 3 minutes per question, so do you have a faster method?

2. The value of ( 1/(1+1<sup>2</sup>+1<sup>4</sup>) ) + ( 2/(1+2<sup>2</sup>+2<sup>4</sup>) ) + ( 3/(1+3<sup>2</sup>+3<sup>4</sup>) ) + .... + ( 99/(1+99<sup>2</sup>+99) ) lies between:

A. 0.46 and 0.47     B. 0.47 and 0.48         C. 0.48 and 0.49      D. 0.49 and 0.50

I am stuck after I convert this into a partial sum: (Sigma) (n=1) (99) [0.5 ( (1/(n<sup>2</sup>-n+1)) - (1/n<sup>2</sup>+n+1)) )]

3. One of the factors of x<sup>6</sup>+10x<sup>3</sup>-27 is

A. x<sup>2</sup> -x+3 B. x<sup>2</sup> -x-3 C. x<sup>2</sup> +x-3 D. x<sup>2</sup> +x+3

No idea how to solve this one, apart from trying each of the given options (polynomial long division).

I have every limited time ( 10 minutes overall in the best case for the 3 questions above) and am not allowed to use a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not feel discouraged by you having a hard time to solve these problems. While there are short solutions, and there will be quite some people finding those fairly quickly, it happens very often that a problem is trivial - if you have seen the required method before - or really very hard. In my case, I had to go back to my mental box of methods from the time when I myself took part in such competitions; and even so they took me a bit longer than these 10 minutes.

Also note that, from what I can see here, you are not required to prove your assumptions; which also allows you to save a lot of time. You merely need to make an educated guess. (May I ask what competition they are from? I actually found them quite enjoyable.)

What I am going to do is first give you some pointers to each problem, for you to maybe give it another go and try to figure them out yourself, and then include a solution, where I will also try to illuminate my thought process - often you (or, at least, I) see a proof where at first you have no idea how people thought of that in a reasonable amount of time, so maybe that will help you out as well.

---

**Hints**

1. Try to find some way to factorize your inequality. This is easier if it is homogenous, you can use that $(x+y)=1$. I know this is a bit of a cruel hint as it takes quite some time and practice, but I haven't found anything more pretty than that, sorry.
2. Your approach works very well, in fact I believe you have done the most part. Now, have you heard of the term 'telescope sum'? If so, try to see what happens if you substitute $n$ with $n+1$.
3. Can you say something about the roots of the polynomial? If so, take a very close look at what is positive and what is negative, and what exactly is under the root. Compare that to the roots of your possible factors.

---

**Solutions/Thoughts on the problems**

Main parts put into spoilers (provided I figured out the way these work correctly), so they don't literally spoil your fun.

**1.**

In my opinion, the nastiest one.

What I saw when I first looked at the task was along the lines of "Yay, AM-GM", together with the reasonable expectation that the maximum value would be reached for $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$. I tried to prove that, and, in hindsight unsurprisingly, failed. The reason for that lies somewhat in the structure of your term, which I didn't realize at first - if you write down $x^4y+xy^4=xy(x^3+y^3)$ you will notice that these two factors assume their maximum value at very different points; the first when both $x$ and $y$ are equal, the other when $x=1,y=0$. This makes use of means fairly difficult - there might still be a beautiful solution involving these, though, if someone finds one I'd be very interested to see it.

Since I know of no other methods to transform the expression to a more approachable form, the next logical step was to try and factorize. I had actually tried this once before, albeit for a very short time, and dismissed it as probably too complicated.

The kind of factorization you should really get used to seeing in these kinds of tasks is something along the lines of

> $x^4y+xy^4=xy(x^3+y^3)=xy(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=^{(x+y=1)}xy(x^2-xy+y^2)$.

What we want is to find an upper bound for this expression, written in an, if possible, homogenous inequality with an expression we can easily calculate. A possible example that fulfills this would be the claim

> $\frac{1}{c}=\frac{(x+y)^4}{c}\geq xy(x^2-xy+y^2)$

for some constant $c>0$. In fact, considering the task, we can assume that $c\in \left\{6,8,12,16\right\}$.

Now going along trying to prove that, we can just put everything on one side:

> $LHS(c):=x^4+(4-c)x^3y+(6+c)x^2y^2+(4-c)xy^3+y^4\geq 0$,

gained by simple transformations of the above inequality. This would certainly be true if our left hand side was a square. Now, if we look at the structure of this, we can see that we have $x^4,y^4,x^2y^2$, the corresponding inner products, and are symmetrical. Because of that, we could be motivated to look at the following:

> $SQR(a):=(x^2+y^2+axy)^2=(x^4+y^4+(a^2+2)xy+2ax^3y+2axy^3)$

for some real $a$. This is what we would like to have, if we can find an $a$ and a $c$ so that $LHS(c)=SQR(a)$, we would have proven that $\frac{1}{c}\geq x^4y+xy^4$ - because, then, $LHS(c)$ would be a perfect square and thus greater than $0$.

But now that we have those two expressions, seeing as they are polynomials, we can simply compare coefficients of $LHS(c)$ and $RHS(a)$. This comparison leads us to $a^2+2=6+c, 2a=4-c$, a system of equations which yields a reasonable solution only for $c=-4$:

We can add both equations, leading to $6+c+4-c=10=a^2+2+2a \Leftrightarrow a^2+2a-8=0 \Rightarrow a\in \left\{2,-4\right\}$.

$a=2$ leads to $4=4-c \Leftrightarrow c=0$, which doesn't really give a great upper bound since $\frac{1}{c}$ wouldn't make a lot of sence then.

$a=-4$, however, leads to $c=12$, which does leave us $\frac{1}{12}$ as our upper bound. Just to make sure we actually assume this maximum, we should check whether our square can actually be $0$, but $(x^2-4xy+y^2)$ takes a positive value for $x=0$ and a negative one for $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$, so that is guaranteed.

Note that instead of forming equations for $c$ one could also have just tried all four options, there might be a pretty argument for why $12$ is the only reasonable try but in that case it has escaped my notice.

So, what we actually did there: We simply put in *some* upper bound $\frac{1}{c}$. Then we transformed into an expression $LHS(c)\geq 0$, and tried to get this expression to be a perfect square. Thus, we looked at the *type* of perfect square this could reasonably be, of the form $SQR(a)$, and then compared coefficients trying to find out which values for $a$ are possible and which values for $c$ they correspond to. Once we did that, we gained an equation system giving us a solution for $c=12,a=-4$, giving us $LHS(12)=SQR(-4)\geq 0$, and we are done.

As a final thought, differentiating this problem by hand seems not to be a sensible solution - you are quite fast, true, but I do not think one would actually find the roots of the resulting polynomial. In my case, I would have probably seen that $\frac{1}{2}$ is one and just assumed it to be a maximum - and failed the question miserably.

To summarize:

> $\frac{1}{12}=\frac{(x+y)^4}{12}\geq x^4y+xy^4 \Leftrightarrow (x^2+y^2-4xy)^2\geq 0$,

gained by trial. And some thoughts, but mostly trial.

**2.**

Not much to say here. First thoughts on my mind: expansion into partial fractions. Ah, wait, he already did that.

Now the crucial thought you seemingly missed was "oh, how nice would it be if all those summands could magically disappear. Could I possibly get that somehow?", and "what happens if I put in $n+1$ instead of $n$?"

Let's just take a look at that:

> $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1}=\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}$.

Ah. That's what happens, and it is wonderful. Because if we just put that into our little sum, we have:

> $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{99}{\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{n=1}^{99}{\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}}-\sum_{n=2}^{100}{\frac{1}{n^2-n+1}}]=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{1}{1^2-1+1}-\frac{1}{100^2-100+1}]=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{18802}$,

which is quite clearly more than $0.49$.

**3.**

Since polynomial division is quite an arduous task, we don't want that. It might work, if you're good with calculations it might even work out in a reasonable time, I was too lazy to do it myself and check how much time it actually takes. However, what we can see is that

> $P(x):=x^6+10x^3-27=(x^3)^2+10x^3-27 $

is a quadratic polynomial in $x^3$, so we can get its roots:

> $\lambda_{1,2}=-5\pm 2\sqrt{13} \quad \Rightarrow\quad x^3\in\left\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2\right\}$.

Note that this also means that we have only $2$ real roots, which are the unique real third roots of our $\lambda_{1,2}$.

Now the interesting part of that is that the roots of a factor polynomials $Q(x)$ must also be roots of $P$ (because $Q(x)=0 \Rightarrow P(x)=Q(x)r(x)=0$), and thus be one of the third roots of one of these $\lambda$s.

Depending on their signs, we get as roots $\pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{i}{2}\sqrt{11}$ (in case the sign before the $3$ is positive) or $\pm\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{13}$ (else).

Now, since we know that the third power of these roots, for any factor polynomial, must be a $\lambda$, we can simply look at what happens if we take these to the third power. We have

> $(a+b\sqrt{x})^3=a^3+3ab^2x+(3a^2b+b^3x)\sqrt{x}$ for rational $a,b,x$.

Now imagine our factor polynomial's non-rational part is of the form $\sqrt{11}$. Raising it to the third power, if you look above, the non-rational part is only multiplied by rational numbers, so there is no way to transform $\sqrt{11}$ into $\sqrt{13}$.

Thus, we can rule out the first two possibilities, meaning the non-rational part is $\sqrt{13}$ and the sign of $3$ is $+$. Now we only need to know the sign of $x$ in our polynomial. For this we can look at another aspect of our roots:

> We have two $\lambda$s, one negative, and one positve; the absolute value of the positive $\lambda_2$ being less than that of the negative $\lambda_2$. Since $x\mapsto x^3$ is monotonous, the same must be true for the roots of our factor polynomial: Imagine our factor polynomial $Q$ would have a negative root $\psi_1$ with a smaller absolute than its positive $\psi_2$. Then $|\lambda_1|=|\psi_1^3|<|\psi_2^3|=|\lambda_2|$, which does not work out.

So we know that our factor polynomial's positive root must be less than it's negative's absolute, and checking for that we can easily see that the sign of $x$ in the factor polynomial must be $+$, and hence we will go for option c.

---

Again, don't feel bad if you didn't get these at first. Some might consider these methods standard, and at some point they will be for you as well, but until then such problems are *hard*. There is no talking around that. So, props for you for trying, and I hope this helped at least somewhat. Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts you put into solving these questions. As you asked, they are from the Mathematics part of Regional stage of the Indian National Talent Search Examination (NTSE) conducted for Class 10 (you could call that Grade 10 by U.S. convention) last year.

Comment: OK, now the actual comment. Your solution to second question (series) is brilliant. For the other two, I tried hard to follow your hints and solutions but couldn't. First I did not understand the terms involving c in the expansion of (x+y)^4. And I understood nothing after the part where you took out the roots of the quadratic equation a^2 + 10a - 27 (assuming a = x^3). If you could explain the others to me, I would be thankful.

Comment: Coincidentally, when I first looked at the first question, my thought was, if I chose anything other than 1/2, the value of either x or y will become quite small, and raising it to power 4 will give a very small value. So even I guessed 1/2 to be the maximum, and seeing 1/16 as an option, I felt the question was done. Actually, differentiation of the given thing is not at all hard - takes about 2 or 2.5 minutes, when I KNOW that the question is to be done via differentiation. The challenging part is to find the zeroes of the resulting polynomial in almost a minute and evaluate them.

Comment: 10th grade? Children these days...

Now, I added some additional explanations. Hope they will help you somewhat; if not feel free to ask again. 

And what you mentioned is exactly what I felt was so nasty about the first task - it is nigh impossible to find the other roots of the derivative with pen and paper, given that amount of time, so one is very tempted to just assume that option D is correct. Would probably have gotten that one wrong myself, given the test.

Comment: I am reading the responses, as I write, but what do you mean by "10th grade? Children these days" ? Are these questions too easy for 10th graders in your country or difficult? Certainly difficult for 10th graders in my country (India).

Comment: Sorry, was meant to be a bit ironic. In the sense of "Children these days must really have polished up their math" or something like that. Nothing against Indian pupils. Because, frankly, these seem a bit hard for tenth graders, especially considering the time limit. But then, again, I do not think they are supposed to be solved by your average student. Made me actually wonder how I'd have done myself back then.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I was just asking. The phrase "What do you mean by" in my above comment was expressing curiosity, not any anger or something. Yes, these are not for average students. They are way advanced.  NOW what is the meaning  of "which are the unique real third roots of our λ 1,2" ?. Is it the third root of x^3? If so, how? And again how did the c land up in the binomial coefficients of expansion of (x+y)^4 in problem 1. And yes, this question  is NOT meant to be done by differentiation (since this for 10th graders, but I think it's the most systematic solution).

Comment: I see I wasn't quite clear with that sentence: By that I meant that we only have two real roots of our polynomial $P(x)$, and these must be third roots of our $\lambda_{1,2}$ (after all, we do have $x^3=\lambda$), because the real third root of any $\lambda$ is unique.
For how $c$ got to the left part: you take the inequality $\frac{(x+y)^4}{c}\geq xy(x^2+y^2-xy)$, multiply by $c$, bring everything to the left side and simplify.

Comment: OK, I mostly got the polynomial question. The reason for my confusion was that I didn't know that the cube root of a number is called the "third root" as you have used it. Also, you did a mistake in typing "Thus, we can rule out the first two possibilities, meaning the non-rational part is 13 − −  √   and the sign of 3  is +". You had to write - (minus) in the end. I did not understand "Imagine our factor polynomial Q  ...  |λ1|=|ψ31|<|ψ32|=|λ2| , which does not work out" so can I assume as a rule in general that |-root| > +root for any polynomial? In 1st question, why SQR(a):=(x2 +y2+axy)2 ?

Comment: Sorry about that, English is not my first language - so any weird terms are probably my bad. Also, the sign is indeed my mistake, thanks.
About the last part: No, you cannot assume that for any polynomial. But in this case, we know that, for $P(x)$, the positive root is less than the negative (let's just ignore the complex ones for now). Now, we also know that the cubes of the roots of our $Q(x)$ must be the roots of $P(x)$. But since for $P$ the negative is more than the positive, the same must now be true for $Q$. Does this make any kind of sense?

Comment: OK, I understood what you want to say. A very clever way to find out the signs of x and 3 (I could never think of it this way). Now I am left with the task of understanding the first question. You take some a in RHS such that a^2 = (x^2+y^2+axy)^2. This means a = (x^2+y^2+axy), but this does not make sense to me, why we chose a to be that specific term and how can it be true? I think I should practice differentiation extensively so that I can differentiate it in 1 minute. Some rules related to polynomial zeroes may help in taking out zeroes of the cubic polynomial I get upon differentiating.

Comment: What we are doing is not solving $a^2=(x^2+y^2+axy)^2$ but rather $(x^2+y^2+axy)^2=(x^4+y^4+(4-c)x^3y+(4-c)xy^3+(6+c)x^2y^2)$. Because given a solution to that, we know that the right hand side is greater or even than $0$. And the way we solve this equation is by comparing coefficients (two polynomials are the same if and only if their coefficients are the same).

Comment: I agree we are not solving a from a^2. But WHY, WHY do we take a = x^2+y^2+axy, because that  means x^2 + y^2 = 0 and xy =1 ???

Comment: (Please note that I'm going to delete the first few of my comments, so this conversation doesn't get blown out of proportions. If you still need any of them, let me know.)
I think you misunderstood. We do *not* solve $a=x^2+y^2+axy$. We solve $(x^2+y^2+axy)^2=LHS(c)$, which is the equation written in the above comment. The reason for doing so is simply that we want to write $LHS$ as a perfect square, the term with $a$ is just an approach to give us an idea of what square exactly that could be. $a$ is merely a crutch to find what we want, if you see it immediately, you don't even need it.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea for question 1 using (x+y=1) repeatedly:
$$x^4 y + xy^4 = xy(x^3 + y^3)=xy(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=xy(x^2-xy+y^2)=xy((x+y)^2-3xy)=xy(1-3xy)$$
Noting that $xy$ attains all values on the interval $(0,\frac{1}{4}]$
and that $$z(1-3z)=-3(z-\frac{1}{6})^2+constant$$
the maximum is attained at $xy=\frac{1}{6}$ and its value is $\frac{1}{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I recently got a method from a booklet of the question paper, with solutions, so I will post it:

Given $(x+y)=1$

So, $(x+y)^3 = 1^3$

On expansion

$ x^3+ y^3 + 3xy(x+y) = x^3+ y^3 + 3xy = 1 $ (since  $x+y=1$)

Applying A.M.-G.M. inequality,

$$ \frac {(x^3+y^3) +3xy}{2} \ge \sqrt{(x^3+y^3)(3xy)} $$
$$ \frac {1}{2} \ge \sqrt{3(x^3+y^3)(xy)} $$
On squaring both sides,

$$\frac{1}{4} \ge 3(x^3+y^3)(xy) $$
$$\frac{1}{4} \ge 3(x^4y+y^4x) $$
$$\frac{1}{12} \ge (x^4y+y^4x) $$